# NUMBERS ONLY: TextBox in GridView without validators

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

How do I make a textbox in gridview accept numbers only without using validators?
I am using C#, ASP.net.

I'm hoping to use KeyPress event or something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtUID" runat="server" CssClass="TextBox" onkeypress="return onlyNumbers(this);"/>

//Restrict the user to key-in chrectors and other special charectors
function onlyNumbers(evt) {
    var e = event || evt; // for trans-browser compatibility
    var charCode = e.which || e.keyCode;
    if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))
        return false;
    return true;
}
```

Reference:- [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/434251/How-to-validate-textbox-inside-gridview-to-accept)

Comment: Where do I paste this code? Sorry I don't know its implementation yet.

Comment: @user3247075 Add the function inside the script tag on your page and the textbox will be inside gridview item template.